# What does it mean when my post is gray?

Tags: support, edits, down-votes, penalty

I hope I didn't do anything wrong, but when I returned from editing my answer, the text of the entire answer was gray.

[image]

What does this mean?

Comment: It just means that it's heavily downvoted. Greying it out acts as a warning to those seeing it that the answer may be wrong or misleading.

Comment: @Mysticial so if I improve it, it might get voted out of the hole?

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink Potentially, sure

Comment: @Bart, Seriously? This is a question of grayed out text, not "colors."

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink grayed out text is colored text. The post Bart linked to answers your question.

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink Yep, seriously. From the duplicate *"Answers with score of -3 or lower get light gray text color and so are all comments made on such answers"*.

Comment: @Bart ok, my bad. Guess I missed that one when I was searching. Good catch!

Comment: @Rory Please. I already got my answer. No need to mark it as a dupe of TWO questions, is there?

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink duplicates serve as a signpost for users with the same problem in the future - it's not a bad thing and I'm certainly not getting at you :)